# Users And Grant Execute Permission Gets Automatically Removed Only In Cloud Sql

Tags: google-cloud-sql

**CLOUD SQL VERSION & DB ENGINE: Currently our CLOUD MYSQL Version is 5.6.21 n DB ENGINE is INNODB**

**1. Create User In Mysql**

Create User 'USERNAME' @ 'HOSTNAME' Identified By 'PASSWORD';

But This User Is Not Permanently Stored In mysql.user Table. This User Getting removed In The Table If Any Issue Comes In Script Side Or Server Restarts...and also sometimes, created user password gets empty.

**2.Likewise Grant Execute Permission For Procedure Also Not Working Properly.**

Grant Execute On Procedure Schemaname . Spname To 'USERNAME'@'%';

This Execute Permission Works For Some Time,But The Privileges Immediately Disappears For The Granted User.

**Other Solutons We Tried Are:**

1.Flush Tables-After Creating User

2.Flush Privilges- After Giving Any Grant Access/Revoke Access

But These 2 Solutions Are Also Not Working In Google Cloud Sql, Still Issue Remains Same.

But This Issue We Dont Have In Local Mysql Version, It Is Reproducible Only On Google Cloud Sql.

We are Struck With This Issue In Our Front End App.

Anyone knows how To resolve This Issue In Google Cloud Sql...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to reproduce the fact that a creating a user doesn't survive a Cloud SQL instances.

Here is how I tested (I replaces some sensitive information with `(edited)`).

First I connect to an existing instance and create a user called `xxx` and checked that it shows up in the `mysql.user` table.

```
$ mysql -uroot -proot -h (edited)
mysql> SELECT host,user,password FROM mysql.user;
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user | password                                  |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root |                                           |
| 127.0.0.1 | root |                                           |
| ::1       | root |                                           |
| localhost |      |                                           |
| %         | root | *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.07 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER xxx@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.61 sec)

mysql> SELECT host,user,password FROM mysql.user;
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user | password                                  |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root |                                           |
| 127.0.0.1 | root |                                           |
| ::1       | root |                                           |
| localhost |      |                                           |
| %         | root | *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B |
| %         | xxx  | *3D56A309CD04FA2EEF181462E59011F075C89548 |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> Bye
```

Then I restart the Cloud SQL instances.

```
$ gcloud sql instances restart (edited) --project (edited)
Restarting Cloud SQL instance...done.
Restarted [https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta3/projects/(edited)/instances/(edited)].
$
```

Then I connected again and check the `mysql.user` tables.

```
$ mysql -uroot -proot -h (edited)
mysql> SELECT host,user,password FROM mysql.user;
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user | password                                  |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root |                                           |
| 127.0.0.1 | root |                                           |
| ::1       | root |                                           |
| localhost |      |                                           |
| %         | root | *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B |
| %         | xxx  | *3D56A309CD04FA2EEF181462E59011F075C89548 |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.07 sec)

mysql> Bye
$
```